# Is there too much code in my view? CakePHP / MVC design pattern

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, cakephp

I am using [google maps cakePHP helper](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-google-map-v3-helper) by dereuromark to show a map in my view. The map also has markers, and each marker has its own associated listener that makes an ajax call.

The map is being rendered perfectly and everything works as expected. However, I am not sure if all this code be separated from my view? I am new to MVC architecture...

```
<h1>Render map</h1>
<?php

// returns true if user logged in
if (!$session->check('Auth.User.id')){
    echo $this->Html->link('Log in',array('controller'=>'users', 'action' => 'login'));
} else 
{   
    echo "Hello " . $session->read('Auth.User.username') . "... ";
    echo $this->Html->link('Log out',array('controller'=>'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
}
echo $this->GoogleMapV3->map(array('map' => array('lat' => '44.230065', 'lng' => '-76.5000', 'zoom' => 14), 'div'=>array('id'=>'my_map3', 'height' => '400px', 'width' => '786px')));

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $options = array(
        'lat' => $post['Post']['lat'],
        'lng' => $post['Post']['lng'],
    );

    $marker = $this->GoogleMapV3->addMarker($options);
    $script = "$.ajax({
                          url: \"show_post.php?q=\"+{$post['Post']['id']},
                          success: function(html){
                            $(\"#results\").html(html);
                          }
                        });";
    $this->GoogleMapV3->addCustomEvent($marker,$script);

}

echo $this->GoogleMapV3->script();

?>
```

If you could also point out any design flaws that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It looks fine to me, but as jcubic says, it doesn't belong here. Then again it looks like you would be the only cakephp submission on codereview. Lonely place to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks fine, as long as you dont do any model calls or to much business logic in the views you are good. you could stick the greeting in an element and just call $this->element('greeting'); at the top instead of the if